# Event Registration on Behalf of a Contact is Broken

Tags: civievent

**Wordpress**: 4.9.6
**Civi**: 5.3.0

When trying to add event registration on behalf of a contact, I encounter a javascript error that is causing a couple issues:

1. I am unable to select an existing event.
2. Any event custom field accordions are missing. They usually appear at the bottom of the other fields.

This is the error that I'm seeing in the Chrome Console:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,**

```
// Event and event-type custom data
CRM.buildCustomData('Participant', eventId, , null, null, null, true);
```

Looking in Participant.tpl, `{/literal}{$eventNameCustomDataTypeID}{literal}` seems to be the missing parameter or token.

I'm wondering if there is a DB issue. I can't find anything useful in the Civi logs. This Civi instance was migrated from Joomla to Wordpress and I'm wondering if something got lost in the move.

Here is a side by side screenshot if you need a visual reference.

[image]

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the option values for Custom data type are disabled or deleted. Make sure you have all the options values required for event are enabled for [Custom data type](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/options?gid=36&reset=1) option group. Here are the options
[image]

If a option value is missing then you will need to add the option value either through UI or api. However for some option values its not possible to add same options with same machine name so it is always better to add such options through API Explorer.

Navigate to CiviCRM >> Support >> Developer >> API Explore. And use the options shown in the image below once you are done with selection then click on execute button for api to process the params you selected.
[image]

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Good thinking Pradeep, but unless I'm missing something, I can't find any disabled options.

Comment: Can you share screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot updated in my original post to include a side by side of what was working and now is not. Does that help you?

Comment: What was working? Did you upgrade CiviCRM??

Comment: This Civi instance was migrated from Joomla to Wordpress and I'm wondering if something got lost in the move.

Comment: Can you screen shot the custom data type option values?

Comment: Participant Event Name was actually missing. I have added it ad you can see here: https://www.evernote.com/l/AMlGJkM3Vj1A65oAtOiyYa7OGS2nDyGUXTcB/image.png Unfortunately it does not fix the issue.

Comment: It depend on how you have actually added. The machine name, value and other things should match.

Comment: Is there a good way to figure out those values?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the solution for your issue. You will need to delete the one which you have just created and create a new one using api explorer with same values shown in the image

Comment: Adding it with the API Explorer worked! I owe you! Thank you!

Comment: Congrats to get it worked. Cheerz