# Event registration from contact's "Events" tab "Add New Registration" is broken

Tags: contacts, registration

**UPDATE 28 OCT:** I just updated to Civi 5.6 and PHP 7.1 and this is still a problem. Grateful for any other suggestions.

I'm having pretty much the same issue as [this person](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25766/event-registration-on-behalf-of-a-contact-is-broken) did not long ago.

I'm unable to add event registrations for contacts through the "Add New Registration" button. The drop-down menu doesn't appear, although oddly if I close the "New Event Registration for" pop-up I can see the drop-down menu 'floating' awkwardly on the page. Looks like a script error. This is affecting the 'event', 'participant role' and 'participant status' options. (Unlike the other person with this issue, my 'accordion' options on the record are appearing just fine.)

Here's trying to use the drop-down - nothing appears
[image]

And here's the weird 'floating' menu which appears if I try to type something then close the "New Event Registration for" modal:

[image]

I've checked my custom data type fields as suggested in that link, but are all as they should be.

What else can I try?

I'm using Wordpress with Civi 5.4 (Civi 5.6 as of 1 Oct).

Comment: Are there any errors recorded in CiviCRM logs or Browser console?

Comment: I don't know how to access/use CiviCRM logs but the browser says:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () https://www.WEBSITENAME.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/css/extra.css?r=oGVP7

Comment: Is it possible for you to add screenshots?

Comment: added to original post. would one of the browser console/error also be useful?

Comment: I think your wp theme or plugin is conflicting with CiviCRM. Did it work before upgrade?

Comment: Yes, it was working with my current WP theme + Civi v5.3. I just updated to 5.4 recently, so that is a likely culprit. I'll see if I can revert back.

Comment: fyi - the term 'profile' has special meaning in civi - and that doesn't apply to what you are describing. just mentioning it to avoid confusion in future

Comment: @afol Your response about the 404 message seems relevant - but because it was posted as a comment, it got cut off.  Could you please repost that info by editing your question?

Comment: I also rewrote your question to replace the word "profile" (which as Pete mentions, refers to a different screen) with references to the correct screens.  Please re-edit if I got something wrong.

Comment: The problem was a conflict with the 'Page Links To' plugin. All sorted now.